# MPI RMA from multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, mpi, openmpi

In my application I am implementing what I would call a "reduce on sparse vectors" via a TBB flow graph compared with MPI one-sided communication (RMA).  The central piece of the algorithm looks as follows:

```
auto &reduce = m_g_R.add<function_node<ReductionJob, ReductionJob>>(
  serial,
  [=, &reduced_bi](ReductionJob rj) noexcept
  {
    const auto r = std::get<0>(rj);

    auto *buffer = std::get<1>(rj)->data.data();
    auto &mask = std::get<1>(rj)->mask;

    if (m_R_comms[r] != MPI_COMM_NULL)
    {
      const size_t n = reduced_bi.dim(r);

      MPI_Win win;

      MPI_Win_create(
        buffer,
        r == mr ? n * sizeof(T) : 0,
        sizeof(T),
        MPI_INFO_NULL,
        m_R_comms[r],
        &win
      );

      if (n > 0 && r != mr)
      {
        MPI_Win_lock(MPI_LOCK_SHARED, 0, 0, win);

        size_t i = 0;

        do
        {
          while (i < n && !mask[i]) ++i;

          size_t base = i;

          while (i < n && mask[i]) ++i;

          if (i > base) MPI_Accumulate(
            buffer + base, i - base, MpiType<T>::type,
            0,
            base, i - base, MpiType<T>::type,
            MPI_SUM,
            win
          );
        }
        while (i < n);

        MPI_Win_unlock(0, win);
      }

      MPI_Win_free(&win);
    }

    return rj;
  }
);
```

This is executed for each rank `r` participating in the calculation, with `reduced_bi.dim(r)` specifying how many elements each rank owns. `mr` is the current rank, and the communicators are created in such a way that the target process is root for each of them.  `buffer` is an array of `T = double` (typically), and `mask` is an `std::vector<bool>` identifying which elements are non-zero.  The combination of loops splits the communication into chunks of non-zero elements.

This generally works fine and results are correct, same as my previous implementation using `MPI_Reduce`.  However, is seems to be crucial that the concurrency level for this node is set to `serial`, indicating that there is at most one parallel TBB task (and thus at most one thread) executing this code.

I would like to set it to `unlimited` to improve performance, and indeed that works fine that way on my laptop with small jobs, running with MPICH 3.4.1.  On the cluster where I really want to run the computation, however, using OpenMPI 4.1.1, it runs for a while before crashing with a segfault and a backtrace involving a bunch of UCX functions.

I wonder now, is it not allowed to have multiple threads in parallel call RMA operations like this (and on my laptop it only works accidentally), or am I hitting a bug/limitation on the cluster?  From the documentation I do not see directly that what I would like to do is not supported.

Of course, MPI is initialized with `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE` and I repeat again that the snippet as posted above works fine, only when I change `serial` --> `unlimited` to enable concurrent execution do I hit the problem on the cluster.

---

In reply to Victor Eijkhout comment(s) below, here is a complete sample program that reproduces the issue.  This runs fine on my laptop (tested specifically with `mpirun -n 16`), but it crashes on the cluster when I run it with 16 ranks (spread across 4 cluster nodes).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

#include <mpi.h>

int main(void)
{
  int requested = MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, provided;

  MPI_Init_thread(nullptr, nullptr, requested, &provided);

  if (provided != requested)
  {
    std::cerr << "Failed to initialize MPI with full thread support!"
              << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  int mr, nr;

  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mr);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nr);

  const size_t dim = 1024;
  const size_t repeat = 100;

  std::vector<double> send(dim, static_cast<double>(mr) + 1.0);
  std::vector<double> recv(dim, 0.0);

  MPI_Win win;

  MPI_Win_create(
    recv.data(),
    recv.size() * sizeof(double),
    sizeof(double),
    MPI_INFO_NULL,
    MPI_COMM_WORLD,
    &win
  );

  std::vector<std::thread> threads;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < repeat; ++i)
  {
    threads.clear();
    threads.reserve(nr);

    for (int r = 0; r < nr; ++r) if (r != mr)
    {
      threads.emplace_back([r, &send, &win]
      {
        MPI_Win_lock(MPI_LOCK_SHARED, r, 0, win);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < dim; ++i) MPI_Accumulate(
          send.data() + i, 1, MPI_DOUBLE,
          r,
          i, 1, MPI_DOUBLE,
          MPI_SUM,
          win
        );

        MPI_Win_unlock(r, win);
      });
    }

    for (auto &t : threads) t.join();

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (mr == 0) std::cout << recv.front() << std::endl;
  }

  MPI_Win_free(&win);
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Note: I am intentionally using plain threads here to avoid unnecessary dependencies.  It should be linked with `-lpthread`.

The specific error I get on the cluster is this, using OpenMPI 4.1.1:

```
*** An error occurred in MPI_Accumulate
*** reported by process [1829189442,11]
*** on win ucx window 3
*** MPI_ERR_RMA_SYNC: error executing rma sync
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this win will now abort,
***    and potentially your MPI job)
```

Possible relevant parts from `ompi_info`:

```
Open MPI: 4.1.1
Open MPI repo revision: v4.1.1
Open MPI release date: Apr 24, 2021
Thread support: posix (MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE: yes, OPAL support: yes, OMPI progress: no, Event lib: yes)
```

It has been compiled with UCX/1.10.1.

Comment: I wonder if the problem is that each thread creates window memory. Shouldn't that be per process?

Comment: Oh, is that stated anywhere explicitly?  OpenMPI doc for MPI_Win_create says " Each process specifies a window of existing memory that it exposes to RMA accesses by the processes in the group of comm."  This I think can possibly be read as "one window per process", but also as "one window per communicator".  MPICH doc for MPI_Win_create says "This routine is thread-safe. This means that this routine may be safely used by multiple threads without the need for any user-provided thread locks."

Comment: Windows are collective over a communicator, so each process in the communicator needs to make some create call. You seem to have each *thread* make the create call. I would move the create call outside your lambda. You probably want to use the windows multiple times anyway, right? Thread-safety only refers to *using* the window, not creating.

Comment: In this case the flow graph topology (not shown in the snippet) actually ensures that there is exacly one window per communicator, and that all processes execute the window creation in the same order. But yes, I ideally want to create all the windows up front.

Comment: In fact, I had a version implemented that way, but it also crashed with OpenMPI, giving me MPI_ERR_WIN.  My theory about that was that maybe there is a constraint that requires window creation and use to be limited to the same thread, but perhaps something else was wrong at the time. If I slightly change my algorithm and use MPI_Accumulate also for rank-local updates, I realize now there is actually a way the use just one communicator and window *per process*, so I will give that version a try.

Comment: Okay, that does not work. Even if I leave it with `serial`, no concurrent calls on the window, it crashes with OpenMPI within `PMPI_Accumulate`, calling `ompi_osc_ucx_accumulate`. Based on that I would repeat my speculation that somehow in this scenario it is important that window creation and operations on it need to happen on a single and same thread. Again no issues running on my laptop with MPICH (and shared memory instead of UCX, naturally).

Comment: Why dont you make a short program that uses threads to create the window? Youir code is obviously too complicated to find the problem.

Comment: Okay, the reported crash with `serial` was a mistake on my part (forgot that the window size should be in *bytes*), but with `unlimited` it crashes again. Good point about writing a short program that reproduces the issue, follows in post below.

Comment: You are missing a `MPI_Win_free` which actually gives a pretty stiff error in my installation, but after that it ran fine on 4 nodes, 80 cores total.

Comment: (To be quite honest: 80 nodes, 320 processes works, 640 fails. But that may be the limitations of my MPI, rather than a problem with your code.)

Comment: My bad about the missing `MPI_Win_free`, sorry!  Indeed I find the error does not trigger all the time, I've had a few runs without problem now also.  Now I added a loop around everything to make it more likely, the updated version above failed for me again just now with merely 16 processes, same error as reported in the description above.

Answer (score -1):

The style in C++ is to put the `*` or `&` with the *type*, not the identifier.  This is called out specifically near the beginning of Stroustrup’s first book, and is an intentional difference from C style.

---

### Create -- Lock -- Unlock -- Free

[⧺R.1](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rr-raii) Manage resources automatically using resource handles and RAII (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization)

Use a wrapper class, either written for the purpose, designed for this C API, a general purpose resource manager template, or `unique_ptr` with a custom deleter, rather than explicit calls that **must** be matched up for correct behavior.

RAII/RFID is one of C++'s fundamental strengths, and using it will go a long way to making your code less buggy and more maintainable in time.

---

Use *destructuring* syntax.

```
const auto r = std::get<0>(rj);
auto *buffer = std::get<1>(rj)->data.data();
auto &mask = std::get<1>(rj)->mask;
```

rather than referring to `get<0>` and `get<1>` you can immediately name the components.

```
const auto& [r, fred] = rj;
auto* buffer = fred->data.data();
auto& mask = fred->mask;
```

Comment: I agree structured bindings can improve readabilty, but in my code I mostly avoid them because they cannot be captured into lambdas at present. (There was some defect identified in the standard that lead to this, I believe, but I don't recall the details now.)  In any case I'm sorry I don't see how this is relevant regarding my MPI question here.

Comment: Is this answer generated by a bot that looks for "lock" in C++ code? It's irrelevant.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout  Not at all.  I accidentally surfed in from [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as it appeared to the right, and didn't notice it switched to the main S.O. site.

Comment: @JDługosz Thanks for clarifying. And thanks for doing code reviews. It's a useful service. There is a lot of bad C++ code out there.